# Error accessing Endpoint page

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Carbon 4.0.1 with ESB and AS features and all of a sudden this morning when I try to access the endpoint page it gives me this error:

```
 TID[-1234] [WSO2 Carbon] [2012-10-22 10:33:57,106] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.ui.client.EndpointAdminClient} - Unable to access the registry instance for the ESB 
org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(O aerationClient.java:165) 
org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.stub.types.EndpointAdminStub.getDynamicEndpoint(EndpointAdminStub.java:2333) org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.ui.client.EndpointAdminClient.getDynamicEndpoint(EndpointAdminClient.java:200) org.apache.jsp.endpoints.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:908) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) 
org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111) 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:265) org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:966) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:643) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:637) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140) 
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80) org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(template_jsp.java:539) 
org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:290) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36) 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:258) org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198) 
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370) org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90) 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I tried to restart, I tried to clean the registry. Nothing is working.

Does anybody had the issue before?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue has been [fixed](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1036) already in the new release.